# Expected &mut [u8] when calling Read::read

Tags: rust

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::TcpListener;

struct Server<'a> {
    ip_addr: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Server<'a> {
    fn receive(&self) {
        let mut received_message_buf: [u8; 100];

        let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind(self.ip_addr).unwrap();
        tcp_listener.accept().unwrap().0.read(&received_message_buf);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I'm getting mismatched types:

```
<anon>:13:47: 13:68 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut [u8]`,
    found `&[u8; 100]`
(values differ in mutability) [E0308]
<anon>:13         tcp_listener.accept().unwrap().0.read(&received_message_buf);
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&mut received_message_buf` instead of `&`.

`&mut` creates a mutable reference (so `read()` can put things into your buffer), while `&` creates an immutable reference.

Comment: I had to initialize received_message_buf but that works.

Comment: Yeah. Didn't notice that variable was initialized. It's always a good idea to initialize your variables, since Rust doesn't have C's "magic auto zero" rule.

Comment: @krzysz00 "magic auto zero rule"? Last I checked, local variables *aren't* initialized to anything in C. This is an example of where Rust is trying to prevent you from using uninitialized values that would have otherwise bit you in C.

Comment: I mis-spoke. I meant the zero-initialized global rule.